# What are some good guidelines for choosing the size of integer types?

Tags: c++, c, linux, performance, memory

I've been searching around a bit, and I haven't really come up with an answer for this.

When I'm programming on embedded devices with limited memory, I'm generally in the habit of using the smallest integral/floating point type that will do the job, for instance, if I know that a counter will always be between zero and 255, I'll declare it as a `uint8_t`.

However, in less memory-constrained environments, I'm used to just using `int` for everything, as per the [Google C++ Styleguide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Integer_Types). When I look at existing code, it often tends to be done this way.

To be clear, I get the rationale behind doing this, (Google explains it very well), but I'm not precisely clear on the rationale behind doing things the first way.

It seems to me that reducing the memory footprint of your program, even on a system where you don't care about memory usage, would be good for overall speed, since, logically, less overall data would mean more of it could fit in CPU cache.

Complicating matters, however, is the fact that compilers will automatically pad data and align it to boundaries such that it can be fetched in a single bus cycle. I guess, then, it comes down to whether or not compilers are smart enough to take, say, two 32-bit integers and stick them together in a single 64-bit block vs. individually padding each one to 64 bits.

I suppose whether or not the CPU itself could take advantage of this also depends on its exact internals, but the idea that optimizing memory size improves performance, particularly on newer processors, is evidenced in the fact that the Linux kernel [relied for awhile](https://lwn.net/Articles/534735/) on gcc's `-0s` option for an overall performance boost.

So I guess that my question is why the Google method seems to be so much more prevalent in actual code. Is there a hidden cost here that I'm missing?

Comment: The Google style guidelines are not considering embedded programming and restricted memory.  Or, restricted memory for the Google guidelines is only having a gigabyte or two of memory available.  If you're programming for 64 KiB or 1 MiB of memory, you are working in a very different environment from that assumed by Google.

Comment: You also need to consider that memory on the stack is more or less free in small quantities, and that saving the memory by using a narrow type *may* require the compiler to emit more instructions. This is the thinking behind using `int` unless you have a reason not to: such as when it is an array element, or a struct or class member.

Comment: Sometimes a larger data type is more performant. For example, `double` can give better performance because modern CPUs are often built to natively work on `double`s instead of `float`s (but if you have a ton of them, then maybe `float` will be better because you can cache more of them...). Also, `-Os` optimizes the number of instructions to be fewer, not the size of the data types being operated on; that flag is orthogonal to your question.

Comment: Yes, I was aware that Google was not targeting embedded environments, my question was more pertaining to why the MCU approach wasn't widely used in order to improve performance generally. Thanks, though, those are definitely some good points that I didn't really consider.

Comment: `It seems to me that reducing the memory footprint of your program, even on a system where you don't care about memory usage, would be good for overall speed, since, logically, less overall data would mean more of it could fit in CPU cache.` being processed data are mainly stored in registers, so it will not suffer from cache miss. But if you use small registers then it'll need a lot of sign/zero extension which will be slower

Comment: Some of the Google advice looks bad to me, and particularly inappropriate for C. Just use the *semantic* types that your platform provides. `size_t` for counting and `ptrdiff_t` for potentially negative differences.

Answer (score 3):

The usual reasons that the "google method"  is commonly used is because `int` is often good enough, and it is typically the first option taught in beginner's material.   It also takes more effort (man hours, etc) to optimise a nontrivial code for "limited memory" - effort which is pointless if not actually needed.

If the "actual code" is written for portability, then `int` is a good default choice.

Whether written for portability or not, a lot of programs are only ever run on hosts with sufficient memory resources and with an `int` type that can represent the required range of values.   This means it is not necessary to worry about memory usage (e.g. optimising size of variables based on the specific range of values they need to support) and the program just works.

Programming for "limited memory" is certainly common, but not typically why most code is written.  Quite a few modern embedded systems have more than enough memory and other resources, so the techniques are not always needed for them.

A lot of code written for what you call "limited memory" also does not actually need to be.   There is a point, as programmers learn more, that a significant number start indulging in premature optimisation - worrying about performance or memory usage, even when there is no demonstrated need for them to do so.     While there is certainly a significant body of code written for "limited memory" because of a genuine need, there is a lot more such code written due to premature optimisation.

Answer (score 2):

"embedded devices ... counter between zero and 255, I'll declare it as a uint8_t"

That might be counterproductive. Especially on embedded systems, 8 bit fetches might be slower. Besides, a counter is likely in a register, and there's no benefit in using half a register.

The chief reason to use `uint8_t` is when you have a contiguous set of them. Could be an array, but also adjacent members in a `class`.

As the comments already note, `-Os` is unrelated - its benefit is that with smaller code, the memory bus has more bandwidth left for data.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience 90% of all code in a bigger project does not need particular optimization, since 95% of all memory consumption and of all execution time is spend in less than 10% of the code you write. In the rest of the code, try to emphasize simplicity and maintainability. Mostly, that means using `ints` or `size_t` as integer types. Usually, there is not need to optimize the size of local variables, but it *can* make sense, if you have a lot of instances of a type in a large array. Item 6 in the excellent book *C++ Coding Standards: 101 Rules, Guidelines and Best Practices* (C++ In-Depth) by Herb Sutter and Andrei Alexandrescu says:

> "Correctness, simplicity, and clarity come first."

Most importantly, **understand where these less than 10% of code are, that really need optimization.** Otherwise, keep interfaces simple and uniform.

Answer (score 0):

Nice discussion! But I wonder why nobody speaks about cpu register size, memory bus architecture, cpu architecture and so on. Saying "int is best" is not a general at all. If you have small embedded systems like 8 bit avr, int is a very bad choice for a counter running from 0 .. 255.

And using int on ARM where you maybe have a 16 bit bus interface can also be a very bad idea if you really only need 16 bits or less.

As for all optimizations: Look in the code the compiler produces, measure how long actions really take and look for memory consumption on heap/stack if it is necessary. It makes no sense to hand craft unmaintainable code to save 8 bits somewhere if your hardware still have MBytes left.

Using tools like valgrind and the profiling supported by the target/compiler give much more ideas as any theoretical discussions here.

There is no general "best integer type"! It depends always on CPU architecture, memory bus, caches and a some more.